# Aligning figure under flushright text

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, align, text

I've a text inserted into a quoting section, set as flushright.

I'm trying to add a figure under the text, but it seems not to be able to stay aligned to the right part of the text.

Here it is an example of my code, I'm using the \usepackage[export]{adjustbox} package.

```
\begin{quotation}
\begin{flushright}
\textit{
When the men on the chessboard\\
get up and tell you where to go\\
}
\par
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=3cm, keepaspectratio, right]{img/alice.jpg}
\end{figure}
\par\end{flushright}
\end{quotation}
```

Here it is a screenshot of what is the result, but I'd like to have the figure's right side aligned with the text on the right.
Some help?

[image: re]

Thanks in advance!
Dario

Comment: that figure is part of the document, not a floating insert so you should just have `\includegraphics`  remove the `\begin{figure}..\end{figure}` and the image will then be flush right

Comment: you have not provided a usable example  but does that `right` key do anything? the standard `\includegraphics` command does not have a key of that name (so it would generate an error)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it worked! it was so easy! Thanks!!!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the right option comes from the adjustbox package.

Comment: questions should almost always come with a complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the image should be part of the quotation, not a floating figure.

```
\begin{quotation}
\raggedleft
\textit{%
When the men on the chessboard\\
get up and tell you where to go}

\includegraphics[width=3cm, keepaspectratio]{img/alice.jpg}


\end{quotation}
```